# How to open a temp directory generated by ioutil.TempDir in terminal

Tags: go

Using Go on MacOS

I'm using the `ioutil.TempDir` command to create a temporary directory, and I want to check if I successfully wrote the content into a file in this dir. However, even using a breakpoint in Goland, whenever I do `ls -a` in the terminal, I cannot found this temp dir.

I wonder where exactly this temp dir is located so that I can check the temp dir **in terminal** to see if my write is successful.

The original code is :

```
func main() {

    dname, err := ioutil.TempDir("/tmp", "sampledir")
    check(err) // a helper function, it panics when err != nil


    fname := filepath.Join(dname, "file1")
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(fname, []byte{1, 2}, 0666)
    
}
```

Comment: You can print `dname` and find out where the temporary directory is.

Comment: Few things to note here: 1) specifying `/tmp` will give undesirable behavior on systems where `/tmp` is not the standard temp dir, so it's generally better to pass `""`; 2) the directory will be named "sampledirXXXX" where `XXXX` is a random string to guarantee uniqueness; 3) [as the docs state](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#TempDir), "It is the caller's responsibility to remove the directory when no longer needed", so breakpoint or not, since you're not deleting it in your code, it's not being deleted; 4) check the error from `WriteFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your file in by running the command in your terminal expecting you are on linux on mac you can do `echo $TMPDIR` to find out your tmp dir:

```
ls /tmp
```

it will show you something like this:
`sampledir854969482`
where starting string is the name you asked for plus a random string to the end.

in that folder you will find your file1

You can print dname to see the full path as suggested by @dlsniper

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    tmpdir, err := ioutil.TempDir("/tmp", "sampledir")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    abspath := filepath.Join(tmpdir, "file1")

    if err = ioutil.WriteFile(abspath, []byte{1, 2}, 0666); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("TMPDIR: %s, FILENAME: %s, PATH: %s\n", tmpdir, "file1", abspath)
}
```

`abspath` gives you the absolute filepath for the file created inside a temporary directory.

For example:

If I run the program:

```
$ go run .
```

Output:

```
TMPDIR: /tmp/sampledir454879696, FILENAME: file1, PATH: /tmp/sampledir454879696/file1
```

Now check the file if it's created with the correct content

```
$ ls /tmp/sampledir454879696/
file1
```

Check the contents:

```
$ xxd /tmp/sampledir454879696/file1
00000000: 0102
```